# Xcode won't create NSManagedObject classes from data model

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, datamodel

I'm starting the process of converting an app to Core Data.  I built the data model and, at first, got Xcode to successfully create `NSManagedObject` custom classes corresponding to the entities. But then I realized the entity and class names didn't have my application prefix, which I thought would dramatically increase the workload of required coding changes for the conversion to Core Data.

So I removed the references to the custom classes, renamed my entities in the data model with my prefix, reset the "class" attribute for each entity to default, and tried to create the custom classes again. I get through the wizard just as before, but now Xcode refuses to create classes for the entities, and instead creates one header-implementation pair with the application name. The .h and .m files correspond to the entity I'm classing (or the last entity in the list when I select multiple), but the names and relationships are invalid, of course, and so are useless. Can anyone explain why Xcode is doing this, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name for the managed objects you are creating wants to correspond to the names of the classes to be created - so I'm not sure what you mean by you reset them to default, but say your prefix is AB, and your class is Thing, then you'd want the class attribute to be ABThing. If you had already done this I may have misunderstood what you meant by returning them to default.
Also, it's worth noting that if you start your application again, after changing the Core Data Model, then you have to delete the current core data model - you can use:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:<URL For your Store> error:&error];
```

Comment: Thomcat, thanks. Class attribute was in fact the issue. Solved the problem by setting it (in the attribute inspector) for each entity to match the entity names, which now have the prefix, as you suggested. Seems obvious now, but what threw me off was that I didn't have to do this the first time; Xcode set the class names automatically.  (I don't have to worry about deleting the changed data model yet, since I'm not even close to the point of trying to build the app.)

Comment: Changing the class names **does not** cause a migration of the model so you do not need to delete your model.  I would also NOT recommend deleting the file every time.  This will hide when you actually need a migration which is useful information. Not every change to the model causes a migration.